# How to Center a image with HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Before i added `position: fixed;` everything was centered then after i added it it went to the left of the browser can anyone help me with my code if so greatly appreciated.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #000f1e;
}

#nav_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 115px;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav  ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav  ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #000f1e;

}

#nav ul li a,visited,hover {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #626262;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #01172c;
  border-bottom:  solid 2px white;
}

#nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}

#nav  ul ul li  a,visited {
  color: #ccc;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #626262;
}

#spon {
  background-color: black;

}

#spon_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 115px;
  text-align: left;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

#nav {
  z-index: -1;
}

#nav_wrapper {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DeLuzens</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" style="height: 125px; width: 100px; text-align: center;">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Store</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Jerseys</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Hoodies</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Shirts</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Headwear</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Roster</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">CS:GO</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Overwatch</a></li>
              <li><a href="">League Of Legends</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Dota 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">News</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks everyone trying to help me fix my code :D

Comment: `z-index` has nothing to do with centering.

Comment: paulie_d before i added z-index the centering worked using text-align: center;

Comment: Regardless, z-index is not related to centering. There is something else affecting that.

Comment: yes i know now thank you it was the positioning set to fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to center a position fixed element is to add

left: 0; and right: 0;

so the css would now look like this

```
.logo {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```